# react onchange push values to objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an dynamic created fields (input tag)

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ native: [{}], rolls: [{}] }) // initial data

{navtive?.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <input
        type="text"
        name={item.id}
        onChange={(e) =>
            handleChange("fee", e.target.value, index, item.id)
        }
        />
...
{rolls?.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <input
        type="text"
        name={item.id}
        onChange={(e) =>
            handleChange("fee", e.target.value, index, item.id)
        }
        />
```

Expected Output:

```
const output = {
    native: [{id: 1, fee: "12"}, {id: 5, fee: "2"}],
    rolls: [{id: 4, fee: "1332"}],
};
```

onChange function :

```
const handleChange = (field, value, index) => {
    setData((prevState) => {
        const nextState = [...prevState];
        nextState[index][field] = value;
        return nextState;
    });
};
```

How to get the expected output ? What am I making wrong in the onChange function.

Thank you

Comment: The expected output doesn't make sense, since the maps are returning react components, not plain objects.

Comment: this is the expected output from onChange - `[{id: 1, fee: "12"}, {id: 5, fee: "2"}]`

Comment: Ah I see. May you also share the current output?

Comment: prevState is not iterable

Comment: `prevState` is an object, not an array.

Comment: how do I do it?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros objects can still be spread.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That's not the problem. The problem is OP wants to spread it into an array and that will throw a TypeError.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-flower-w6xef - sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add more arguments to `handleChange` for this output. `type` - to understand what property is `native` or `rolls`. `id` - id from current data element. [Example - sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-cori-70zj3)

```
const handleChange = (type, field, value, index, id) => {
    setData((prevState) => {
      const nextState = [...prevState[type]];
      nextState[index] = {
        ...prevState[type][index],
        id,
        [field]: value
      };
      return {
        ...prevState,
        [type]: nextState
      };
    });
  };
```

JSX

```
handleChange("native", "free", e.target.value, index, item.id)
```

Comment: TypeError: prevState[type] is not iterable ` const [data, setData] = useState([
    { native: [{}], rolls: [{}] },
  ]);`

Comment: You have mistake , correct `useState({ native: [{}], rolls: [{}] })` instead of `const [data, setData] = useState([ { native: [{}], rolls: [{}] }, ]);`

Comment: `data` is object not array, see above your question